# VB.NET VS2017 net 4.6.1 moving AspNetIdentity 2.2.2 code from website project to reusable DLL since I have 80+ web sites to convert

Tags: vb.net, webforms, asp.net-identity, reusability

Using package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.2.2.2\lib\net45\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.dll

The following IntranetSecurity.vb code works when called within the website code base.
`Dim manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager(Of ApplicationUserManager)()`
returned an ApplicationIserManager like it should.

But when I moved my IntranetSecurity.vb class code module into a class library DLL
and called it from my website, the code returns nothing.
**`Dim manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager(Of ApplicationUserManager)()`**
returns nothing

Each of our webpages that required security rights start with this code on the webpage Page_Load

```
**Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
Dim SEC As New IntranetSecurity(Page, "Add Intranet User")**
```

**HOW CAN I REFERENCE THE ApplicationUserManager OF THE CALLING CODE??? **

```
Public Class IntranetSecurity
    Inherits Page
    Implements IDisposable

    Public Sub New(ByRef p As Page, ByVal ApplicationName As String)
        'Used by every web page within 'Your Options' menu
        pgMain = p
        LoadAuthenticatedUser(p)
        If IsValidUser Then
            If Not HasAccessToApplication(ApplicationName) Then
                'Authenticated User has No right to access ApplicationName value
                p.Response.Redirect("AccessDenied.aspx")
            Else
                'Authenticated User has right to access ApplicationName value
                Dim i As Int16 = 0  'For debug purposes
            End If
        Else
            'Not a valid intranet user so they can't possibly
            'have any rights to anything...so deny access by default.
            p.Response.Redirect("AccessDenied.aspx")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub LoadAuthenticatedUser(ByRef p As Page)
        pgMain = p
        ' Verify the current user is Authenticated
        _AspNetUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId()
        _UserName = User.Identity.GetUserName()
        _IsValidUser = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
        If IsValidUser Then
            **Dim manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager(Of ApplicationUserManager)()**
            'Dim manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager(Of ApplicationUserManager)()
            Dim appUser = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId())
            ' Load web page variables and properties for the Authenticated pplicationUser
            _UserId = appUser.UserId
            _UserName = appUser.UserName
            _UserPartName = appUser.UserPartName
            _FirstName = appUser.FirstName
            _MiddleName = appUser.MiddleName
            _LastName = appUser.LastName
            _FullName = appUser.FullName
            _EmployeeNumber = appUser.EmployeeNum
            _CostCenter = appUser.CostCenter
            _PrimaryDept = appUser.PrimaryDept
            _IsGeneric = appUser.IsGeneric
            _RolesList = ApplicationList(manager)
        Else
            ' Clear web page variables and properties for the NONE Authenticated ApplicationUser
            _UserId = String.Empty
            _UserName = String.Empty
            _UserPartName = String.Empty
            _FirstName = String.Empty
            _MiddleName = String.Empty
            _LastName = String.Empty
            _FullName = String.Empty
            _EmployeeNumber = String.Empty
            _CostCenter = String.Empty
            _PrimaryDept = String.Empty
            _IsGeneric = String.Empty
            _RolesList = String.Empty
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Function HasAccessToApplication(ByVal ApplicationName As String) As Boolean
        ' This code verifies the Authenticateds User has rights to the ApplicationName
        Dim intFoundAtPosition As Integer = RolesList.IndexOf(ApplicationName)
        If intFoundAtPosition = -1 Then
            Return False
        Else
            Return True
        End If
    End Function

    Public Overrides Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
    End Sub
End Class
```

I have tried a variety of ways to get this functionality to work from a DLL class method.
Everything returned nothing.
I want to keep the interface the same to minimize the impact on the existing code base which is 80+ website applications.
I even gave up on the interface impact just to get something working and attempted to pass the ApplicationUserManager object byref to a new New method, but I could not get the syntax correct.

Environment Win10, VB.net VS2017, .Net framework 4.6.1, ASP.Net webforms,
Using packages
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.2.2.2\lib\net45\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.dll
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.2.2.2\lib\net45\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.dll
Microsoft.Owin.4.0.0\lib\net451\Microsoft.Owin.dll
EntityFramework.6.2.0\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll

Comment: Where is pgMaim coming from? It is used in the class, but I don't see any define for that variable? Same goes for IsValiduser. Where is that routine, and how does it work?

Comment: I shortened the code by eliminating some of the variables and properties.
After Implements, Protected pgMain As Page

Comment: Dim _IsValidUser As Boolean = False
    Public Property IsValidUser() As Boolean
        Get
            Return _IsValidUser
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            _IsValidUser = value
        End Set
    End Property

Comment: Ok, so in your project in references you referenced the .dll. And in the above code you create a new instance of that class. I assume that new instance does get created, and I have to assume at that point I can't see why the class would not work (as opposed to including the source code class in the project.  Only issue I can think of is this is a web site, and not a web site application. If web site then referenced assembly (.dll) has to be placed in the bin folder. However, I assume the "new" of that class works ok. So, we missing somthing here, but it's not clear what.

Comment: This is how I approached this.  I have a working web application using my IntranetSecurity.vb and HRPWrapper.vb (accesses our Employee user data) classes.  It Authenticates my User using a custom ApplicationUser with additional user values instead of using IdentityUser. It retrieves all the Roles assigned to this user. which I use to build a left menu of all the applications this user has rights too.

Comment: I am attempting to minimize the impact of our existing code base of 80+ VB web applications when I implement this new security model.  
The working code calls the New method within IntranetSecurity.vb passing the page and name of the web application.  
When IntranetSecurity.vb is within the web application, this Dim manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager(Of ApplicationUserManager)() returns the user information.  
When IntranetSecurity.vb is within a separate VB project, this `Dim manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager(Of ApplicationUserManager)()` returns nothing.

Comment: `Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load`
        `Dim SEC As New IntranetSecurity(Page, "Add Intranet User")`

Comment: that looks good to me. I can only suggest that (hopefully) this is a web site applcation, as references are far better resolved then using just a "web site". So, for a web site, you go file->open web site, but for a project, then you open the .sln project file. Assuming the New instance create of the class works, then this should work just fine.... I thus assume you are referring the .dll in the web project to use that external class then. You can include both projects into the web project (assuming a web app). However, either way, we assume a valid reference to that .dll.